# Excel VBA Multicolumn Listbox add non contiguous range

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Im trying to figure out how to add a non contiguous range of cells in a row to a multicolumn Listbox, but only the second line below works.

```
lbxSelectable.List = Sheets("DB").Range("A1,B1,C1").Value
lbxSelectable.List = Sheets("DB").Range("A1:C1").Value
```

Is there any efficient function which will allow me to *select certain columns* in a row and stick it in an entry of a *multicolumn* list box?

Many thanks

Comment: Answered an old question, but demonstrate a tricky way to populate a listbox with non contiguous column data **without any loop** using rather unknown features of the ►`Application.Index` method :-) @Gelion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a non contiguous range of cells in a row to a multicollumn Listbox, you have to first create an Array and then assign it to the `.list` of the listbox. Here is an example.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Ar() As String
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1,C1,E1")

    i = 1

    For Each cl In rng
        ReDim Preserve Ar(1, 1 To i)
        Ar(1, i) = cl.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = i - 1
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"
        .List = Ar
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Though this is an elder post, maybe your are interested in a tricky way to populate a listbox with non contiguous column data **without any loop** :-) @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 0):

**I. Display non contiguous column data without loops**

In addition to *Siddharth's* valid solution I demonstrate a flexible approach **without any loop** necessity. 
Furthermore I added the possibility to display not only one, but *even more data rows* as well as to define a varying start row (e.g. `m=2` in this example:-).

**Applied method step by step**

After fully qualifying a range reference in section `[0]`, defining start row and end row in section `[1]`, 
section `[2]` does the main work by assigning the wanted columns to a variant datafield array 
using *advanced filtering possibilities* of the ► `Application.Index` method •):

- a) First it gets the entire data range content from top row 1 to right column E,
- b) eventually starts from 2nd row m (i.e. omitting title row) to lastrow n and
- c) finally filters columns 1,3,5 (= A ,C, E) via the `Application.Index` method.

Section `[3]` fills the listbox with data from the array which have to be *2-dimensional*. 
If data sets have more than one item 'rows' they get assigned to the ►`.List` property of the listbox - cf. section [3]b).

If, however there is only **one** single data row, the array `v` would loose one needed dimension, so it has to be *transposed* via the `Application.Transpose` method (changing rows and columns, but regaining the 2nd dimension!) and then assigned to the listboxes ►`.Column` property.

•) cf. [Insert first column in datafield array without loops or API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

```
Option Explicit                                    ' declaration head of code module

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' [0] Declare variables start row, lastrow, (variant) datafield array, worksheet   
      Dim m&, n&, v, ws As Worksheet               ' data types Long, Long, Variant, WorkSheet
      Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet")  ' << change to your sheet name
' [1] define Start Row m and Last Row n (based on items in column A)
      m = 2: n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' [2] assign data to variant datafield array
      v = Application.Index(ws.Range("A1:E" & n).Value2, Evaluate("row(" & m & ":" & n & ")"), Array(1, 3, 5))
' [3] fill ListBox with array contents
  With ListBox1
      .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"
      If m = n Then                         ' Case a) SINGLE data row only (needs transposed data)
         .ColumnCount = UBound(v, 1)        '         counts 1st dimension of v
         .Column = Application.Transpose(v) '      << assign transposed array v to listbox COLUMN property
      Else                                  ' Case b) several data rows
         .ColumnCount = UBound(v, 2)        '         counts 2nd dimentson of v
         .List = v                          '      << assign array v to listbox LIST property
      End If
  End With
End Sub
```

**II. Simple alternative with adapted `ColumnWidths`**

Of course, it would be possible to collect the whole data range columns `A:E`, but to define **zero widths** for the columns to be omitted in display via the `ColumnWidths` property:

```
With ListBox1
  .ColumnWidths = "50;0;50;0;50"
  ' ...
End With
```

Enjoy it :-)