# Filtered list only diplaying 1 line in listbox

Tags: excel, vba, filter, listbox

I have a form that is populating data from a separate spreadsheet which connects to a sharepoint site using a web query.

My script filters the data and returns the results into a listbox.

Everything seems to work fine, but when I filter two fields it will only return a single result and not the list of data. I have stepped through the code and it is filtering correctly, just not displaying the results.

The most confusing thing is I have the exact same code with only one filter on a different page of the form that returns the data correctly.

The working code is:

```
Private Sub UpdateActiveButton_Click()

Dim rngVis As Range

Dim Lob As String
Lob = LOBComboBox.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Workbooks.Open("Data ssheet")
    With Sheets("Data")

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("Table_owssvr").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        .AutoFilterMode = False

If Lob = "ALL CS" Then

With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:CM"))
            .Sort Intersect(.Cells, .Parent.Columns("J")), xlAscending, Intersect    (.Cells, .Parent.Columns("A")), , xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "CS", "CS2", "CS3"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngVis = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then Me.ActiveListBox.List = rngVis.Value

            ActiveListBox.ColumnWidths = "33;40;0;0;0;80;50;60;0;130"
        End With


Else


If Lob = "ALL MH&S" Then

With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:CM"))
            .Sort Intersect(.Cells, .Parent.Columns("J")), xlAscending, Intersect    (.Cells, .Parent.Columns("A")), , xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "MHS", "MHS2"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngVis = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then Me.ActiveListBox.List = rngVis.Value

            ActiveListBox.ColumnWidths = "33;40;0;0;0;80;50;60;0;130"
        End With

       End If        

End With
    .Close False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This returns the full list in my listbox 'ActiveListBox', however the below code will only return the first result:

```
Private Sub CommandButton10_Click()

Dim rngVis2 As Range

Dim Lob2 As String
Lob2 = LOB2ComboBox.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Workbooks.Open("data ssheet")
    With Sheets("Data")

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("Table_owssvr").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        .AutoFilterMode = False

If Lob2 = "ALL CS" Then

With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("Table_owssvr"))
            .Sort Intersect(.Cells, .Parent.Columns("J")), xlAscending, Intersect(.Cells, .Parent.Columns("A")), , xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
            "CS", "CS2", "CS3"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Stage 4", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngVis2 = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not rngVis2 Is Nothing Then Me.ActiveListBox2.List = rngVis2.Value

            ActiveListBox2.ColumnWidths = "33;40;0;0;0;80;50;60;0;130"

End With

Else


If Lob2 = "ALL MH&S" Then

With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:CM"))
            .Sort Intersect(.Cells, .Parent.Columns("J")), xlAscending, Intersect(.Cells, .Parent.Columns("A")), , xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "MHS", "MHS2"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
           .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Stage 4", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngVis2 = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rngVis2 Is Nothing Then Me.ActiveListBox2.List = rngVis2.Value

            ActiveListBox2.ColumnWidths = "33;40;0;0;0;80;50;60;0;130"
        End With

        End If            

End With
    .Close False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: can a listbox accept a non-contiguous range of cells? I'm not sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if the answer is "No", so that may explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like David is correct.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621758/excel-vba-multicollumn-listbox-add-non-contiguous-range) on SO.

Here's the summary:

You cannot use a non-contiguous range of cells, so you need to assign the values of those cells to an array first, and then assign the array to the listbox's `.List`.

Here's the sample provided:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Ar() As String
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1,C1,E1")

    i = 1

    For Each cl In rng
        ReDim Preserve Ar(1, 1 To i)
        Ar(1, i) = cl.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = i - 1
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50;50"
        .List = Ar
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, some of the ranges are quite long, so for processing I think I'm goping to copy and paste the values to a seperate sheet before populating the list box!

Comment: Excellent. If your issue is fully resolved, can you accept the answer? If you're having any trouble with it, please edit your question or start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The copy to another range on another sheet seems best.

Something like:

```
Sub listit()
    Dim Rng As Range, Cl As Range, RaTo As Range, Ri&, Rl&

    Rl = Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row  ' end of column "E"

    If Rl > 11 Then    ' only taking from row 11 down to row RL
        Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("e11:e" & Rl).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        '
        ' Range to on another sheet  FilteredWork .. as work space only

        Set RaTo = Sheets("FilteredWork").Range("B10").CurrentRegion
        RaTo.ClearContents

        'Rng.Copy RaTo(1, 1)  if one column

        UFJ.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2

         ' pick what columns of the filtered data you need for what columns of the list
        For Each Cl In Rng
            Ri = Ri + 1
            RaTo(Ri, 1) = Cl(1, 1).Value  ' col "E"
            RaTo(Ri, 2) = Cl(1, -2).Value  ' col "B"
        Next Cl
    End If

    Set RaTo = Sheets("FilteredWork").Range("B10").CurrentRegion  ' find the new data
    UFJ.ListBox1.RowSource = "FilteredWork!" & RaTo.Address

End Sub
```