# VBA Excel - add header to combobox when using AddItem

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, header

I have a list with values I like to add to combobox in my userform.

The values I want are in Column A and Column Z (so values from 2 columns). I manage to add the values with the AddItem function but struggling to add a header to the dropdown (a few posts said this is not possible).

As alternative I saw ListFillRange but I cannot figure out if this can be used for two columns which are not next to each other.
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

> `a few posts said this is not possible`

I usually do not reply to questions which do not show any efforts but this is an interesting one. I tend to **agree** with you that lot of people think that you **cannot** show headers in a `ComboBox`.

**But it is possible** to show headers in a `Combobox`. Here is a demonstration. You will of course have to take help of a helper sheet for this if you **do not** want to change the original sheet.

**TEST CASE**

For our demonstration, we will take 2 non-contigous range `A1-A5` and `D1-A5`

[image]

**LOGIC**

1. You will copy the relevant data to a new sheet.
2. Convert the range to a table
3. Set columnheads to true of combobox
4. Set rowsource to the relevant table range from helper sheet.

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Input sheet. Change as applicable
    Set wsInput = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Add a new sheet. Hide it (Optional)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    
    '~~> Copy the non-contigous range to the new sheet
    wsInput.Range("A1:A5").Copy ws.Range("A1")
    wsInput.Range("D1:D5").Copy ws.Range("B1")
    
    Dim rng As Range
    
    '~~> Get your range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:B5")
    
    '~~> Convert range to table
    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "MyTable"
    
    '~~> Few combobox settings and we are done
    With ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = "MyTable"
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Delete the temp sheet we created
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**ALTERNATIVE**

If you are not ok with the idea of helper sheet and are ok to sacrifice on the header part then you can populate a combobox using non contigous ranges. See [Excel VBA Multicolumn Listbox add non contiguous range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621758/excel-vba-multicolumn-listbox-add-non-contiguous-range). You will of course have to edit the code to suit your needs. Since there are two columns only, your final array would look like `Dim Ar(1 To LastRow, 1 To 2)`. This array will hold values from both columns.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to add headers above listboxes and comboboxes.  It seems a bit like a sledgehammer to crack a nut but sometimes the nut has to be cracked, and all the other methods and tools that I have seen also fall into the category of sledgehammer.

To make this as simple as possible for myself I have defined a class called clsListBoxHeaders and I include that code below.  Then suppose you have a ListBox with 3 columns you need to

1. Tell the class which ListBox it is to work on
2. Tell it what the headers are
3. Tell it the column widths

To do this insert the following code in your user form

```
Dim lbHeaders As New clsListBoxHeaders
    Set lbHeaders.ListBox = ListBox1
    lbHeaders.Headers = "First Header;Second Header;Third Header"
    lbHeaders.ColumnWidths = "40;50;60"
```

Note that the number of headers and the number of columnwidths must match exactly the number of columns in your listbox/combobox

To clear the header data use:

```
lbHeaders.Clear
```

If you want to format the labels (e.g. font) then you can access the labels as a variant array

```
lbHeaders.Labels
```

The class module code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

' clsListBoxHeaders - Display header info above a ListBox or ComboBox

' To use this class in your project:
'   Add a class module called clsListBoxHeaders and paste this code into it
'   For each ListBox or ComboBox for which you wish to display column headers insert the following code in your userform:

'   Dim lbHeaders As New clsListBoxHeaders
'    Set lbHeaders.ListBox = ListBox1
'    lbHeaders.Headers = "First Header;Second Header;Third Header"
'    lbHeaders.ColumnWidths = "40;50;60"

'Note that the number of headers and the number of columnwidths must match exactly the number of columns in your listbox/combobox

' To clear the header data use:
'   lbHeaders.Clear


Const LabelHeight As Integer = 10   ' Height of the header labels.
Const LabelOffset As Integer = 10   ' Offset to get the header to align correctly to first column in listbox

Private myListBox As Object
Private myParent As Object
Private lblHeaders() As MSForms.Label
Private sColumnWidths() As Single

Public Property Set ListBox(ListBox As Object)
    Set myListBox = ListBox
    Set myParent = ListBox.Parent
End Property

Public Property Let Headers(sHeaders As String)
    Dim lLeft As Long, vHeaders As Variant
    Dim iCol As Integer
    With myListBox
    vHeaders = Split(sHeaders, ";")
    ReDim lblHeaders(.ColumnCount)
    If UBound(sColumnWidths) = 0 Then
        ReDim sColumnWidths(.ColumnCount)
        For iCol = 1 To .ColumnCount
            sColumnWidths(iCol) = .Width / .ColumnCount
        Next
    End If
    lLeft = LabelOffset
    For iCol = 1 To .ColumnCount
        Set lblHeaders(iCol) = myParent.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        With lblHeaders(iCol)
            .Top = myListBox.Top - LabelHeight
            .Left = lLeft + myListBox.Left
            .Width = sColumnWidths(iCol)
            .Height = LabelHeight
            lLeft = lLeft + sColumnWidths(iCol)
            .Visible = True
            .Caption = vHeaders(iCol - 1)
            .ZOrder fmZOrderFront
        End With
    Next
    End With
End Property

Public Property Let ColumnWidths(ColumnWidths As String)
    Dim vSplit As Variant
    Dim lLeft As Long
    Dim iCol As Integer
    With myListBox
    vSplit = Split(ColumnWidths, ";")
    ReDim sColumnWidths(.ColumnCount)
    For iCol = 1 To .ColumnCount
        sColumnWidths(iCol) = vSplit(iCol - 1)
    Next
    lLeft = LabelOffset
    If UBound(lblHeaders) > 0 Then
        For iCol = 1 To .ColumnCount
            With lblHeaders(iCol)
                .Left = myListBox.Left + lLeft
                .Width = sColumnWidths(iCol)
                lLeft = lLeft + sColumnWidths(iCol) ' + LabelOffset
            End With
        Next
    End If
    End With
End Property

Public Property Get Labels() As Variant
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim vLabels As Variant
    
    With myListBox
    ReDim vLabels(.ColumnCount - 1)
    For iCol = 1 To .ColumnCount
        Set vLabels(iCol - 1) = lblHeaders(iCol)
    Next
    End With
    Labels = vLabels
End Property

Public Sub Clear()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(lblHeaders)
        myParent.Controls.Remove lblHeaders(i).Name
    Next
    Class_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim lblHeaders(0)
    ReDim sColumnWidths(0)
End Sub
```