# Populate last rows of Excel sheet to VBA UserForm List

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I want to populate lets say 5 last row to user Form List, but not like from A B C D columns like now but choose specific ones like A B D G can someone help with that?

My code:

```
With wbMaster
    
     lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     lr3 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Row
     lr4 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-2).Row
     lr5 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-3).Row
     lr6 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-4).Row
     lr7 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-5).Row
     lr8 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-6).Row
     lr9 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-7).Row
   
    TestSheet.lstLast.ColumnCount = 3
    For Y = 1 To 3
      
        X(1, Y) = .Cells(lr2, Y)
        X(2, Y) = .Cells(lr3, Y)
        X(3, Y) = .Cells(lr4, Y)
        X(4, Y) = .Cells(lr5, Y)
        X(5, Y) = .Cells(lr6, Y)
        X(6, Y) = .Cells(lr7, Y)
        X(7, Y) = .Cells(lr8, Y)
        X(8, Y) = .Cells(lr9, Y)
       
    Next Y
            TestSheet.lstLast.List = X
End With
```

I tried for but with loops did not help me

Comment: To load a non contiguous range to a listbox, see this [Excel VBA Multicolumn Listbox add non contiguous range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621758/excel-vba-multicolumn-listbox-add-non-contiguous-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Populate a List Box With n Last Rows of Specified Columns of a Range

**The Main Function**

- This will return the array with the results. It calls both helper functions.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Function GetLastRowColumns() As Variant
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const LAST_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 5
    Dim SRC_COLS(): SRC_COLS = Array("A", "B", "D", "G")
    
    ' Reference the Source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    ' Reference the Source Data range ('srg').
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Source Table Range (has headers)
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' no headers
    End With
    
    ' Using the 'RefLastRows' function, reference the last rows ('slrg').
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = RefLastRows(srg, LAST_ROWS_COUNT)
    If slrg Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' not enough rows
    Debug.Print slrg.Address
    
    ' Using the 'GetRangeColumns' function, return the values from the last rows
    ' in a 2D array ('Data').
    Dim Data(): Data = GetRangeColumns(slrg, SRC_COLS)

    GetLastRowColumns = Data

End Function
```

**The Helper Functions**

```vb
Function RefLastRows( _
    ByVal SourceRange As Range, _
    ByVal LastRowsCount As Long) _
As Range
    With SourceRange.Areas(1)
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        If rCount < LastRowsCount Then Exit Function
        Set RefLastRows = .Resize(LastRowsCount).Offset(rCount - LastRowsCount)
    End With
End Function

Function GetRangeColumns( _
    ByVal SourceRange As Range, _
    SourceColumns()) _
As Variant

    Dim scLo As Long: scLo = LBound(SourceColumns)
    Dim scUp As Long: scUp = UBound(SourceColumns)
    Dim scJag(): ReDim scJag(scLo To scUp)
    
    Dim Data(), scrg As Range, rCount As Long, sc As Long
    
    With SourceRange.Areas(1)
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        If rCount = 1 Then ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        For sc = scLo To scUp
            Set scrg = .Columns(SourceColumns(sc))
            If rCount = 1 Then Data(1, 1) = scrg.Value Else Data = scrg.Value
            scJag(sc) = Data
        Next sc
    End With
    
    ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To scUp - scLo + 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, dc As Long
    
    For sc = scLo To scUp
        dc = dc + 1
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Data(r, dc) = scJag(sc)(r, 1)
        Next r
    Next sc
    
    GetRangeColumns = Data

End Function
```

**The Form Code**

- This basic form code was copied from the page [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/), a must-read,  which is an article about user forms by the SO legend [Mathieu Guindon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mathieu-guindon).
- The form has two buttons: `OkButton` and `CancelButton`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private cancelled As Boolean
 
Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property
 
Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Hide
End Sub
 
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    OnCancel
End Sub
 
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub
 
Private Sub OnCancel()
    cancelled = True
    Hide
End Sub
```

**The Form Calling Code**

- It is expected that you'll add the two command buttons (rename appropriately) and a list box to the form.
- In a standard module (not the user from module) you can use the following code.

```vb
Sub UserFormTest()
    
    Dim Data(): Data = GetLastRowColumns
    
    With New UserForm1 ' adjust!
        With .Controls("ListBox1") ' adjust!
            '.Clear
            '.ColumnWidths = "30;30;30;30"
            .ColumnCount = UBound(Data, 2)
            .List = Data
        End With
        .Show
        If Not .IsCancelled Then
            MsgBox "Selected the 'OK' button.", vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "Selected the 'Cancel' or the 'X' button.", vbExclamation
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**The Worksheet Calling Code**

- It looks like you were playing around with a worksheet Active-X list box. If the list box is in another worksheet you can use the following code. It is a more compact version: it uses both helper functions, but not the main function.

```vb
Sub WorksheetTest()
 
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const DST_LIST_BOX_NAME As String = "ListBox1"
    Const LAST_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 5
    Dim SRC_COLS(): SRC_COLS = Array("A", "B", "D", "G")
    
    ' Reference the Source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    ' Reference the Source Data range ('srg').
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' Source Table Range (has headers)
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' no headers
    End With
    
    ' Using the 'RefLastRows' function, reference the last rows ('slrg').
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = RefLastRows(srg, LAST_ROWS_COUNT)
    If slrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    
    ' Using the 'GetRangeColumns' function, return the values from the last rows
    ' in a 2D array ('Data').
    Dim Data(): Data = GetRangeColumns(slrg, SRC_COLS)
    
    ' Populate the list box ('lst') in the Destination worksheet ('dws')
    ' with the values from the 2D array ('Data').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)

    Dim lst As MsForms.ListBox
    Set lst = dws.OLEObjects(DST_LIST_BOX_NAME).Object

    With lst
        '.Clear
        .ColumnCount = UBound(Data, 2)
        .List = Data
    End With
    
End Sub
```